# Change the default size of Ean-13 in mpdf

Tags: php, css, mpdf

Is there any way to change the default size of ean-13 to mpdf.
This is my code, but it is too big for me.

```
<barcode code="'.$Ean.'" type="EAN13" class="barcode" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the barcode section of the [mpdf manual](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/barcode.html) there is a size parameter you can pass:

> $size Specifies the size of the barcode.
>
> $size (float) will scale the nominal size of the barcode as a factor
>   of 1
>
> size="1.5" will generate a barcode one and half times the height and
>   width of the nominal size set in mPDF
>
> NB Sizes between '0.8' and '2.0' are recommended for EAN13 and similar
>   barcodes.
>
> Default: '1'

Specifying this setting should allow you to control the size of your barcode, e.g:

```
<barcode code="'.$Ean.'" type="EAN13" class="barcode" size="0.8" />
```